# Compile and run Oracle openscript by batch file

Tags: java, openscript

I need to run my (Oracle) openscript testing scripts from a custom-made UI. So I need to be able to compile and run these scripts without the OpenScript UI.

I can see, that there are batch files like "runScript.bat" as a part of installation, but I have no idea, if they are any good...

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below command to run from batch file. 
Save below commapnd in .bat file and execute

```
cd c:\oracleATS\openScript
runScript "c:\OracleATS\OFT\Default\TestScript\TestScript.jwg"
```